# Spring Boot Webapp: compression is not applying

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Not working on non @ResponseBody-annotated methods. Am I misunderstand something? What could be the root cause?

Compression applied on the @ResponseBody method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/property/{id}/pano.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getPanoXml(@PathVariable("id") Property property) {
    return assetsProvider.loadUnderlyingObject(property.getPanoXml()).getObject();
}
```

[image: gzipped]

Compression is not applied on the non @ResponseBody method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/property/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, Locale locale) throws NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException {
    LocalizedProperty lp = repository.findProperty(id, locale.getLanguage());
    // TODO: replace with custom exception
    if (lp == null)
        throw new NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException("get", PropertiesController.class);
    model.addAttribute(lp);

    return "property/show";
}
```

[image: not gzipped]

**Lib versions and Config:**

Spring Boot Version: 1.2.4.RELEASE
View Renderer: Thymeleaf

App config:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    compression: "1024"
    compressableMimeTypes: "application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain"
```

Comment: Some software (like anti-virus) can modify your traffic and strip gzip encoding. When you request this page (http://stackoverflow.com/q/31562729/5032339) with the same browser, do you get compressed result?

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right, looks like a corporate antivirus software uncompresses the response before it reaches my browser.

Comment: could one of you answer or close this question then? Leaving this question as unanswered is not really helping the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roman answered (in comments to question), corporate anti-virus software was modifying the incoming traffic so that all the responses were unzipped.